# Postfix virtual domain - accessing and sending emails

Tags: postfix, dovecot

I inherited a postfix + dovecot setup and now need to add additional virtual domain to it. (example.com and example.net)

I followed the guide [here (section separate domains, UNIX system accounts)](http://postfix.cs.utah.edu/VIRTUAL_README.html) and confirmed that it works - I can receive emails sent to another domain.

Now the question I have is **how do I access that account on that domain?** I can login to *user@example.com* and read emails directed to *mapped_user@example.net* but the sending address would be incorrect if I were to reply.

Do I need to reconfigure Dovecot or is this just Postfix thing I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, you cannot. If the user had the same username as the mapped email, then you could just alternate between them without issue - the mail would ultimately reside under user@exmaple.com, but you could send as user@exmaple.net freely.

However, because the accounts have different names, you can't achieve this, because mapped_user@exmaple.net does not have anywhere to store email. Your option here is to to create an email account for mapped_user@example.net - you're no longer working with an alias, you're now asking for an account.

All that aside, if your mail server is set up to allow it, there's probably nothing stopping your users just changing the "FROM" address in their email client to the alias domain - that's how I achieve this. But again, I don't think that would work if the usernames are not identical.

I have my primary domain, .xyz, and my secondary, .io. I have .io as a virtual domain in postfix, this allows the email directed at my account (joe@domain.io/xyz) to appear in the same mail box. When replying to email, I have my FROM address set itself to whatever the original email was sent to. Email still ends up in the same place ultimately. I don't think this would work if I tried to use a different username however, e.g, joe-test@domain.io. The mail wouldn't know where to go, because it wouldn't be able to find joe-test on the .xyz domain.

I could of course be wrong, but I don't see how mail could ever be delivered if no account exists for the alias user.

By best suggestion would be to just accept it for the majority of accounts and allow users to inform third parties of the change. For any vital inboxes, set up a mailbox on the .com domain by the same username as the .net domain, then you can freely switch between sending as either.

Answer (score 0):

The account is not on a domain but on the server. The address you use for sending mail is configured on *mail user agent* (MUA) instead of the mail server – if you use Dovecot as IMAP server and Postfix as a *mail submission agent* (MSA), you are using an external MUA; webmail being an "internal MUA". You may need to add *addresses* or *identities* there. The MUA may or may not be able to choose sender address automatically based on who has received the original message you are replying to.

Unlike in Exchange server, where every account has primary `SMTP:` address that gets used for all outgoing mail, Postfix & Dovecot combination doesn't have that kind of limitations. However, it could be possible that someone has set [`smtpd_sender_login_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps) and [`reject_sender_login_mismatch`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#reject_sender_login_mismatch) to prevent users from using email addresses of other users, e.g.

```
smtpd_sender_login_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_sender_login_mismatch
smtpd_client_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
```

In this example, all the domains are [`virtual_alias_domains`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_domains) and all addresses are mapped to users in `virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual`. This kind of configuration has one advantage: the [`smtpd_sender_login_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_login_maps) uses the same format as [`virtual_alias_maps`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#virtual_alias_maps) and gets automatically updated every time you add a virtual address. If you use the domains as [`mydestination`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mydestination) and still want to use such limitations, you will need to update the table used for sender login maps accordingly.